# mod_wsgi apache2 loading failure

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I've set this up using a multitude of documentation and repeatedly get the same result.  This particular one below is following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#daemon-mode exactly as it says.  I need help!

```
[Sun Oct 09 14:52:09.208810 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 53237] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
[Sun Oct 09 14:52:09.208844 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 53237] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
[Sun Oct 09 14:52:09.210835 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 53237] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 09 14:52:09.210866 2016] [core:notice] [pid 53237] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Oct 09 14:52:09.245977 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 53240] mod_wsgi (pid=53240): Call to 'site.addsitedir()' failed for '(null)', stopping.
[Sun Oct 09 14:52:09.246021 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 53240] mod_wsgi (pid=53240): Call to 'site.addsitedir()' failed for '/home/addohm/projects/rtservice/projectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages'.
```

Comment: You need to show the mod_wsgi configuration you are using. The first problem is that you are trying to make mod_wsgi use a Python 2.7 virtual environment when mod_wgsi is compiled for Python 3.5. You cannot do that.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I've already made that change, but still have the same problem.  Going to post all the necessary info into a new thread.  Thanks for following up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948367/apache-mod-wsgi-error-with-django-in-virtualenv  Sorry for making a new thread but the post is very long and too long for simply commenting.

Answer (score 1):

If You are trying to deploy Django web on EB with a single EC2 instance and want to configure SSL on that single EB instance instead of doing at ELB.

Step-1 Login to EC2 and do `sudo yum install mod24_ssl`.

Step-2 `sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`

Step-3 Paste below config

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/venv
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"

Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/static/
<Directory /opt/python/current/app/static>
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/<yoursite>/wsgi.py

<Directory /opt/python/current/app>
 Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi-ssl processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
 python-home=/opt/python/run/venv/ \
 python-path=/opt/python/current/app user=wsgi group=wsgi \
 home=/opt/python/current/app
WSGIProcessGroup wsgi-ssl
```

Step-4
CERTIFICATE.crt > "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"

PRIVATE KEY.crt > "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"

Step-5 Restart server

Try Https on your site, should be working fine.