# apache mod_wsgi error with django in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I can't seem to find a good answer to this.  Who needs to own the virtualenv when running it as a WSGIDaemon?  I assume on my OS (Ubuntu 16) www-data, but I want to be sure.  Trying some new things to get this thing working based off of the answer from this post...

[django apache configuration with WSGIDaemonProcess not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284814/django-apache-configuration-with-wsgidaemonprocess-not-working)

Does the django project, the virtualenv folder, or both need to be owned by the apache group?  What ownerships need to be in place to serve a django project without specifying a port?  Why do I get the following?

The root problem:

```
 Call to 'site.addsitedir()' failed for '(null)'
```

When I start apache, I get this error.  I've followed several different guides, including:
http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html
and
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/
but have had zero success.

My virtual environment path is `/usr/local/virtualenvs/servicesite`

My django project path is `/home/addohm/projects/rtservice/servicesite`
*this is where manage.py resides*,
which leaves `/home/addohm/projects/rtservice/servicesite/servicesite` as the location of my wsgi.py.

**wsgi.py:**

```
SERVICESITE = ['/usr/local/virtualenvs/servicesite/lib/python3.5/site-packages']

import os
import sys
import site

prev_sys_path = list(sys.path)

for directory in SERVICESITE
        site.addsitedir(directory)

new_sys_path = []
for item in list(sys.path):
        if item not in prev_sys_path:
                new_sys_path.append(item)
                sys.path.remove(item)
sys.path[:0] = new_sys_path

"""  **Doesn't seem to work, throwing error in apache logs**
site.addsitedir('/usr/local/virtualenvs/servicesite/lib/python3.5/site-packages')
"""

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "servicesite.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
DJANGO_PATH =  os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '..')
sys.path.append(DJANGO_PATH)
```

**apache2.conf**

[...]

```
WSGIDaemonProcess servicesite python-path=/home/addohm/projects/rtservice/servicesite:/usr/local/virtualenvs/servicesite/lib/python3.5/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup servicesite
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/addohm/projects/rtservice/servicesite/servicesite/wsgi.py

Alias /static/ /home/addohm/projects/rtservice/servicesite/static/
<Directory /home/addohm/projects/rtservice/servicesite/static/>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/addohm/projects/rtservice/servicesite/servicesite>
        <Files wsgy.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

[...]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not have need to change anything in the original `wsgi.py` generated by Django for you. It is generally sufficient to have:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "servicesite.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Your Apache configuration should then preferably be:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess service site python-home=/usr/local/virtualenvs/servicesite \
    python-path=/home/addohm/projects/rtservice/servicesite
WSGIProcessGroup servicesite
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/addohm/projects/rtservice/servicesite/servicesite/wsgi.py

Alias /static/ /home/addohm/projects/rtservice/servicesite/static/
<Directory /home/addohm/projects/rtservice/servicesite/static/>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/addohm/projects/rtservice/servicesite/servicesite>
        <Files wsgy.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

That is, use `python-home` for the location of the directory specified by `sys.prefix` for the virtual environment. Avoid using `python-path` and referring to the `site-packages` directory. Using `python-home` has been preferred way for a very long time and using it ensures that things fail in a more obvious way when you don't do things the correct way.

A few very important things.

The first is that mod_wsgi must be compiled for the specific Python major/minor version you want to use.

Second, the Python virtual environment must be created from the same Python installation as mod_wsgi was compiled for. You can't have mod_wsgi compiled against a system Python installation, but have your virtual environment based off a separate Python installation for same major/minor version in `/usr/local`.

Third, the user that Apache runs your code as must have read access to any directories/files for the main Python installation, the virtual environment and your application code. When you stick stuff under a home directory, it will not generally have access as the home directory prohibits others from reading anything in the home directory.

Fourth, if the mod_wsgi daemon process group is set to run as a different user than the Apache user, the Apache user still must at least have ability to read the `wsgi.py` file and all the directories down to that point.

Further reading on virtual environments which is more up to date:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with.html

Comment: This code seems to fix the root problem I was seeing.  I just need to figure out my permissions now.  I did add the django project directory to the :www-data group, but that may not have been enough.  To be continued.  Gotta pick up the wife from the airport!  Thanks so much for your help.  I look forward to getting this behind me, thanks to your help :)

Comment: @GrahamDempleton would you recommend instead keeping all the Django project files in a '/var/www/projects' folder instead, and leave the virtualenv folders in '/usr/local/virtualenvs'?

Comment: @GrahamDempleton On your first/second point, if I understand you correctly, I basically need to make sure my virtual environment was created under the same python environment that I pip installed the mod_wsgi in?   How can I be sure everything aligns correctly?

Comment: If you are configuring Apache manually for mod_wsgi, you wouldn't even normally be using the ``pip`` installable ``mod_wsgi``. You would be using the ``mod_wsgi`` that was installed as a system package to match the Apache installation, or you would have compiled from ``mod_wsgi`` source using the ``configure/make/make install`` method. The ``mod_wsgi-express`` script you get when you run ``pip install mod_wsgi`` is a way of doing things that is entirely separate. Is ``mod_wsgi`` installed as a system package? How otherwise have you installed ``mod_wsgi``?

Comment: If I remember right, mod_wsgi was not included in the distribution repositories (at least for my version), so I ended up using pip install.  I'll remove it and recompile using make.

Comment: How did you the mod_wsgi.so file get into the Apache modules directory then? There is an extra step you can do to use the mod_wsgi.so from mod_wsgi-express, but it isn't the normal process and why confusing.

Comment: So, the apache logs show this...  `[Mon Oct 10 06:25:01.824614 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 30855] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
[Mon Oct 10 06:25:01.824647 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 30855] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.` - I think I'm okay.

Comment: Now I'm getting `Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.`.  The logs show `[Mon Oct 10 08:42:10.250294 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 35749] [client 192.168.2.249:51129] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/addohm/projects/rtservice/servicesite/servicesite/wsgi.py

`  Going to move everything to /var/www/projects and modify all the permissions.  I think it's a better idea anyway since I hope to set this server up with multiple websites.

Comment: I got it worked out.  With the exception of this hiccup `Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'` it's all worked out.  Thanks so much for your help!  Now...  gotta set up a DNS server :)